# Calculate percentage in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities, `Projects` and `Tasks` with their respective repositories.

I am trying to create a function that will calculate the `totalNumberOfTasks()` , `totalNumberOfCompletedTasks()` and `getPercentComplete()`.

- `totalNumberOfTasks()` basically will fetch all the data related with a specific `project_id` from the tasks table.
- `totalNumberOfCompletedTasks()` will query all the data relevant with specific project_id but only those marked as `COMPLETED` from the tasks table.
- `getPercentComplete()` will calculate the percent based on the `totalNumberOfTasks()` and `totalNumberOfCompletedTasks()` functions and print in the view file.

I have tried doing `{{ project.tasks|length }} %` in Twig file which fetched only the total number of tasks relating to that specific `id`. How do I get total number of tasks and completed tasks, find the percentage then show it in the view file where every projects are shown?
Sorry for my english. I am just not being able to make the question  more understandable.

`Project` entity:

```
<?php

namespace TaskManagerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Projects
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TaskManagerBundle\Entity\Repository\ProjectsRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Projects
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tasks", mappedBy="projects")
     */
    protected $tasks;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="completed", type="boolean")
     */
    private $completed;

    /**
     * @var \Date
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="due_date", type="date")
     */
    private $dueDate;

    /**
     * @var \Date
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="date")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \Date
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated", type="date")
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Projects
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set completed
     *
     * @param boolean $completed
     * @return Projects
     */
    public function setCompleted($completed)
    {
        $this->completed = $completed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get completed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getCompleted()
    {
        return $this->completed;
    }

    /**
     * Set dueDate
     *
     * @param \Date $dueDate
     * @return Projects
     */
    public function setDueDate($dueDate)
    {
        $this->dueDate = $dueDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dueDate
     *
     * @return \Date
     */
    public function getDueDate()
    {
        return $this->dueDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \Date $created
     * @return Projects
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \date
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \Date $updated
     * @return Projects
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \Date
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedValue()
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setUpdatedValue()
    {
        $this->updated = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function getNumberOfTasks()
    {

    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tasks = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add tasks
     *
     * @param \TaskManagerBundle\Entity\Tasks $tasks
     * @return Projects
     */
    public function addTask(\TaskManagerBundle\Entity\Tasks $tasks)
    {
        $this->tasks[] = $tasks;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tasks
     *
     * @param \TaskManagerBundle\Entity\Tasks $tasks
     */
    public function removeTask(\TaskManagerBundle\Entity\Tasks $tasks)
    {
        $this->tasks->removeElement($tasks);
    }

    /**
     * Get tasks
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTasks()
    {
        return $this->tasks;
    }
}
```

`Tasks` entity:

```
namespace TaskManagerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Tasks
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TaskManagerBundle\Entity\Repository\TasksRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Tasks
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Projects", inversedBy="tasks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="projects_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $projects;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated", type="date")
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="date")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="due_date", type="date")
     */
    private $dueDate;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="completed", type="boolean")
     */
    private $completed;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Tasks
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Tasks
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     * @return Tasks
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Tasks
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set dueDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dueDate
     * @return Tasks
     */
    public function setDueDate($dueDate)
    {
        $this->dueDate = $dueDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dueDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDueDate()
    {
        return $this->dueDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set completed
     *
     * @param boolean $completed
     * @return Tasks
     */
    public function setCompleted($completed)
    {
        $this->completed = $completed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get completed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getCompleted()
    {
        return $this->completed;
    }

    /**
     * Set projects
     *
     * @param \TaskManagerBundle\Entity\Projects $projects
     * @return Tasks
     */
    public function setProjects(\TaskManagerBundle\Entity\Projects $projects = null)
    {
        $this->projects = $projects;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get projects
     *
     * @return \TaskManagerBundle\Entity\Projects
     */
    public function getProjects()
    {
        return $this->projects;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace TaskManagerBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use TaskManagerBundle\Entity\Projects;
use TaskManagerBundle\Form\ProjectType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entities = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:Projects')->findAll();

        return $this->render('TestBundle:Default:index.html.twig', 'projects' => $entities]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please attach `Project` and `Task` entities and your controller.

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk updated. Can you help me with this. I am not able to get the percentage. I was just transforming my todo demo app from yii2 to symfony2 just to get hold of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can archive this problem using the [Doctrine Criteria](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) instead of make a custom Repository method. As Example you can add the following method to your Projects Entity class:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;  // IMPORT THIS!
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Projects
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TaskManagerBundle\Entity\Repository\ProjectsRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Projects
{
 ...
    public function getCompleteTasks()
    {
        $expr = Criteria::expr();
        $criteria = Criteria::create();

        $criteria->where($expr->eq('completed', true));

        return $this->getTasks()->matching($criteria);
    }

    public function getNumberOfTasks()
    {
        return $this->getTasks()->count();
    }

    public function getPercentComplete()
    {
        $percentage = 0;
        $totalSize = $this->getNumberOfTasks();
        if ($totalSize>0)
        {
            $completedSize = $this->getCompleteTasks()->count();
            $percentage =  $completedSize / $totalSize * 100;
        }

        return $percentage;
        }
...
}
```

Then you can use in your Twig template as follow:

```
{{ project.percentComplete|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: ok so now how do i print the percentage in the view file. Do I use {{ project.getPercentComplete }}

Comment: yes, or more simply `<h1>{{ project.percentComplete|number_format(2, '.', ',') }} %</h1>`

Comment: Object of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection could not be converted to int
Got this error

Comment: sorry for the trouble you are going through though

Comment: excuse me, i don't understand what you mean... is this is working now? Is what you expect? Let me know :)

Comment: no it is not working. I was saying sorry because u were going through the trouble of solving my problem

Comment: Oh! is strange! I use this approach in some cases and work well for me! If you want go to this way tell me what error you see. If you prefer some other way don't worry, you are welcome!

Comment: Worked as a charm. Thank you